# Is Elmah Safe to Use on a Production SharePoint/ASP.NET Server?

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net

I'm making a big push for my company to start utilizing [Elmah](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx) in our development and acceptance testing servers but I'm still a little bit leery about deploying it to production. My question is: Is Elmah safe to use on a production SharePoint server? Does it cause additional overhead or are there any other issues associated with it? Do any of you have experience using Elmah in a production environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have any issues with Elmah on any of our farms.

The only thing i'd bring up is please please please remember to secure your elmah installation if its going to be public facing.  Depending on the verbosity of your error messages, you will likely be exposing a lot of sensitive information when exceptions are thrown.  Judging by a quick google search for elmah.axd many people skip this important step...

Full instructions for securing elmah can be found at [SecuringErrorLogPages](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. My solution would probably be to whitelist our development group and deny everybody else.

Comment: Link is Dead...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! I know many people that add this as the first thing to any project they do, and I've used it many times myself.  The overhead is not noticeable and the benefits are great.  It's fully production ready and has been stable on many sites for years.  Plenty of burn-in time.

I haven't run it on Sharepoint per se, but I can't imagine any issues.  If there are any, they will occur immediately due to config conflict and shouldn't creep up over time, so you'll know quickly in your post deployment testing.